# MVC core 3 as IIS10 application in a Website. But the root is the website, not the virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, asp.net-core-3.0, iis-10

I'm trying to deploy an MVC Core 3.1 project.
I can only deploy it on a Webserver as "Application" of a specific Website.
So the application is reachable at [Website]/[ApplicationName] but every reference (static files, routing, ...) from there is wrong, because the Root is considered to be the Website, not the virtual directory of the IIS application.

The CSS folder points to [Website]/css, not [Website]/[ApplicationName]/css.

I tried setting app.UsePathBase("/[ApplicationName]") in the startup.cs but nothing changes.

What can I do to set the root at [Website]/[ApplicationName]?

Cheers

Comment: Where in your pipeline did you add `app.UsePathBase`?

Comment: Just before app.UseHttpsRedirection() and app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: Could you please post the IIS folder schema for the web site in your post? I have created a test demo on my side and i put the application as nested into another application on IIS it works well. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4DPr.png).